# OLE DB Source Component to OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSMS and BIDS and I'm trying to do a simple extract and load. I created a table in SQL with data and I'm using BIDS OLE DB source Component (with no data conversion transform) and using OLE DB Destination component. I configured the source editor to my DB and selected the table I had just created and clicked on columns and selected the columns. In the OLE DB Destination editor, I selected the same connection manager and clicked on new for table, mapped the columns and then executed the package and it ran. Problem is, no data when I  go to the new table in SQL. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any error, when you run your package. please check output tab window.

Comment: I suggest that add data viewer in order to check data that want to insert into destination table.

Comment: I just did. Still no data.

Comment: You must survey your package and check query of Source DB Component.

Comment: Got it. I had Execute SQL Task in the control flow with a SQL Statement to delete table. I went back and disabled it, inserted values into the table, then ran it again and it worked. Thanks Mehdi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data viewer in order to check data that wanted to insert into destination table. If you don't see any data in data viewer, must be check your scenario and query of source DB component and source data.